# Fix an area map using CSS so it displays correctly on iPhones and small devices?

Tags: iphone, html, css

Here is the link to the website I am making for a client:

http://knowyourheart.co.uk/alisir/diff/

It's working fine on all desktop browsers but when viewed on iPhone or small devices it's not aligning properly.

It's mainly because the image which have copyright info and social icons are #map based, so it's a 1200px image.

Is there any way I can get around this?

I really appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: @wildpeaks a code example might help neolance, they are a CSS newcomer

Answer (score 0):

For `<img>` tags (which may ultimately be preferable), you need to set the % width for the image like this:

CSS:

```
img{   
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

For `<area><map>` elements (in your case), you need to use the CSS transform property like this:

CSS (for 50% smaller):

```
area {
   zoom:.5; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5);  /* iPhone Safari browser specific */
  -o-transform: scale(.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(.5)"
}
```

To get the rest of the page to also scale appropriately, you might also have to set the other `<div>` containers to a % width.

You can do a quick and dirty test of mobile phone size on a laptop just by resizing the width of the browser window. If your content still fits in view at the minimum width, you are in good shape, at least if the phone is held horizontally.

Comment: I tried doing that but As you can see on the website i used #map feature to make the  social icons clickable if i try to shrink it ( on width by %) the coordinates are all messed up and i am not able to click the icons

Comment: Rest of the page is aligned good on all devises only this footer thing is giving me problem

Comment: do you know how to inspect the actual CSS that is getting applied to this footer image? you can do this in Chrome developer tools or firebug. my guess is the `img{   
   max-width: 100%;
}` is getting overruled only on the footer image by some other CSS. But this is the rule to use.

Comment: I forgot the mention the footer dont is inside a div which is 100% set and padding of some 20px from above div and below  bottom of the website  but the actual image is not a css its simple this code

<div align="center">
  <img src="images/bottom.png" style="max-width:95%" height="47" usemap="#Map" >
      <map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="984,9,1039,41" href="#"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="1084,9,1143,41" href="#"  alt="" title="">
  <area shape="rect" coords="1185,10,1245,40" href="#"  alt="" title="">
    </map>    
    </div>

Comment: I set the MAxwidth rule as tim peterson i still have the problem as you can see i set max width as 95%

Comment: for me if I change the max-width on images/bottom to 100%, then the social icons are in view, albeit rather squished. What is your development set up? Are you on Chrome? The developer tools are VERY handy for troubleshooting CSS.

Comment: do you want to discussion this on chat? it is prompting me this question,

Comment: yes defenetly my gtalk is floralchamp@gmail.com i really really thank you soo much for taking your precious time to help me out

Comment: @floralchamp, i might suggest deleting your comments containing your skype username and email, no biggie but just thought i'd mention in case you forgot